# What is required to deploy Next.js without Vercel?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, server, next.js

I need to deploy a Next.js app, but not on Vercel. What are the steps to deploying it?

I used to drag and drop the `build` folder from React to the server, but in Next.js I don't know which files I should deploy and how.

NB: I am using `getServerSideProps` so `next export` will not work.

Comment: A synical take is that creators of nextjs (Vercel) doesn't want you to run Next.js without Vercel. Sure, there are some projects which implement workarounds, but  in practice I think you'll find developers running Next.js outside of Vercel being  unhappy. Just yesterday regarding [next-on-pages](https://github.com/cloudflare/next-on-pages): `How is anyone using next-on-pages for anything critical? For me it randomly starts to fail, with vague error messages in the event log.` on Cloudflare's [discord](https://discord.com/channels/595317990191398933/1135899572141568050/1185910547921768488)

Answer (score 7):

The minimum requirement to deploy a Next.js app is Node.js at build time to run `next build`. If you want to use server features, you'll also need Node.js at runtime, which can be done using the `next start` command. Otherwise, you can use static only features by targeting `output: "export"` ([docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports)) and host on any static web server. Therefore, you have a selection of providers out there. If you start using certain Next.js features, then you may need to do some stitching between providers to mimic what Vercel is capable of. That is not cheap nor fast, as you can imagine.

Of course, the recommended way to deploy a Next.js app is to use the company behind the framework: [Vercel.com](https://vercel.com)*. Vercel will take the requirements of your Next.js app and deploy globally using its [Edge Network](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/overview) along with many other components, such as [Edge Functions](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions), [Image Optimization](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/image-optimization) infrastructure, etc. Deploying with a top-notch provider will improve not only the experience of your users but also the workflow of your own team, even if you are working alone.

* *Disclaimer: I work for Vercel.*

Answer (score 0):

Because I need to deploy on a variety of servers and platforms, not all of which desire to have an additional node express server running, I have transitioned to Gatsby.js entirely.  Same static page delivery as Next.js but no need for node or express on the server.  Drag and drop the build folder into any server folder - just like React.